# Small, inexpensive tracking device for bikes

Tags: tracking-devices

I work with a homeless resource center that would like to start lending bicycles as a service. Obviously, we'd like to have a way of tracking the bikes down if one goes missing.

Specifically, I need a tracking device that is easy to use and unobtrusive. We don't have a great deal of money to throw around, so the lower the price the better.

Comment: Before I provide an answer, are you aware/worried that these tracking devices might be themselves stolen/vandalized?

Comment: @Adam Alas, no system is perfect. In addition to the tracking devices, there will be an application process. If there's a way to bolt the device to the bike, that would be helpful too.

Comment: by "tracking" you mean "computationally check if a bike is missing" or "geo-tracking the bike when you figured out that it was missing"?

Comment: @comicurus The latter. We'd like to have a way of tracking a bike down if it goes missing.